# Number of rows in predicted data frame does not equal number of rows in new data frame fed to predict function

Tags: r, predict

I have a data frame that I split based on a vector of factors. I'm trying to create a model for each data set and then create a set of predicted values from them.

I'm trying to span the predicted values over a large number of values (e.g. `length.out = 500`), but when I feed the `predict` function with a new data set with 500 rows, it still spits out a predicted data frame that's the same length as the original data frame fed into the model.

```
data(mtcars)
rownames(mtcars) <- NULL #I've ran this code with and without this line, both times it gave the same result

mtcars.split <- split(mtcars, mtcars$cyl)

mtcars.split <- lapply(mtcars.split, function(x){
  rownames(x) <- NULL
  x <- droplevels(x)
  return(x)
})

mtcars.lm <- lapply(mtcars.split, function(x){
  lm(disp ~ wt, data = x)
})

mtcars.fitted <- mapply(x = mtcars.lm, y = mtcars.split, function(x, y){
  newdata = data.frame(wt = seq(min(y$wt), max(y$wt), length.out = 500))
  fitted <- as.data.frame(predict(x, new.data = newdata, se = T))
  return(fitted)
}, SIMPLIFY = F)

lapply(mtcars.fitted, nrow)
lapply(mtcars.split, nrow)
```

I tried running the linear model for the entire data set and it did the same thing.

```
mtcars.lm.all <- lm(disp ~ wt, data = mtcars)
newdata <- data.frame(wt = seq(min(mtcars$wt), max(mtcars$wt), length.out = 500))
nrow(as.data.frame(predict(mtcars.lm.all, new.data = newdata, se = T)))
```

Even attempting to subset the data set didn't make any difference.

```
mtcars.head <- head(mtcars, n = 16)
mtcars.head.lm <- lm(disp ~ wt, data = mtcars.head)
predict.mtcars <- as.data.frame(predict(mtcars.head.lm, 
                                        new.data = data.frame(wt = seq(min(mtcars.head$wt), 
                                                                       max(mtcars.head$wt), 
                                                                       length.out = 500)),
                                        se = T))
nrow(predict.mtcars)
```

Am I missing something here? This used to work but it doesn't seem to work now. Even restarting the R session or my computer doesn't seem to make it work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the argument in the `predict` function is not `new.data` but `newdata`.

Attached the desired result.

```r
data(mtcars)
rownames(mtcars) <- NULL #I've ran this code with and without this line, both times it gave the same result

mtcars.split <- split(mtcars, mtcars$cyl)

mtcars.split <- lapply(mtcars.split, function(x){
  rownames(x) <- NULL
  x <- droplevels(x)
  return(x)
})

mtcars.lm <- lapply(mtcars.split, function(x){
  lm(disp ~ wt, data = x)
})

mtcars.fitted <- mapply(x = mtcars.lm, y = mtcars.split, function(x, y){
  newdata = data.frame(wt = seq(min(y$wt), max(y$wt), length.out = 500))
  fitted <- as.data.frame(predict(x, newdata = newdata, se = T))
  return(fitted)
}, SIMPLIFY = F)

lapply(mtcars.fitted, nrow)
#> $`4`
#> [1] 500
#> 
#> $`6`
#> [1] 500
#> 
#> $`8`
#> [1] 500
lapply(mtcars.split, nrow)
#> $`4`
#> [1] 11
#> 
#> $`6`
#> [1] 7
#> 
#> $`8`
#> [1] 14


mtcars.lm.all <- lm(disp ~ wt, data = mtcars)
newdata <- data.frame(wt = seq(min(mtcars$wt), max(mtcars$wt), length.out = 500))
nrow(as.data.frame(predict(mtcars.lm.all, newdata = newdata, se = T)))
#> [1] 500
```

<sup>Created on 2020-07-22 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>